# I am trying to use the help function in python but getting an error

Tags: python-3.x

help(time.sleep)
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Comment: Try `import time`?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the program you have to import all the modules you need. To do this you need to use the `import` keyword followed by the package name.

```
import time

help(time.sleep)
```